# Oracle: changing the DB_RECOVERY_FILE_DEST without pre-existing folder?

Tags: database, oracle, rman

I'm working on a web interface for modifying Oracle database backup settings. One of the options I want to give users is where to set the flash recovery area. As far as I know, the only way to change this is by executing something like:

`ALTER SYSTEM SET DB_RECOVERY_FILE_DEST='C:\file\path' SCOPE=BOTH SID='*';`

The problem is that if the file path is some path that doesn't already exist on the system, it isn't created automatically, and this script fails. Does anyone know if there is a way to instruct Oracle to make that directory for me or if there is a PL/SQL script I can use to create a directory on the physical disk (I.E. not a CREATE DIRECTORY call)?

Comment: Just out of interest, why would anyone want to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you really want to do this, write a Java stored procedure (stored as an Oracle object) that calls the mkdir function on a file object.  You'll need to use dbms_java.grant_permission to grant java.io.FilePermission privileges.

Comment: I kind of figured it would be something like this. Thanks for the concise and simple response!